# Why do the files I’ve moved return to its previous location?

Tags: macos, finder

I moved some files from one folder on Desktop to another folder in Documents.  But after I put my MacBook Pro with OS X Mavericks to sleep, I found those files return to their original location.

What is the cause of it?

Comment: Are they in both locations now or *just* the original location?

Comment: How did you move them?

Comment: In the original location **only**.

Comment: Drag & Drop....

Comment: So your question is, why doesn't it move instead of "still exists in original location". Edit: Are you using TotalFinder or any finder plugin? Edit2: Do you see them being moved, or don't they move at all?

Comment: They appeared to be moved when I moved them but then they went back to their original location. I am not using any Finder plugins.